# MongoDB Kafka connector not serializing JSON values

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka source connector that is getting data from MongoDB. The data itself is a simple JSON that looks something like this in the DB:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "20230317",
        "idA" : "123456",
        "idB" : "TEST"
    },
    "count" : NumberLong(4)
}
```

And my source connector configurations are as follow:

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
```

Now I am able to see this data coming into my Kafka topic, but strangely it was recognized as a String. And due to that, when I try to add any SMT to the connector, I am getting error like this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [flattening], found: java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Thank you in advance.